# How to refresh a div without reloading the entire page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, refresh, partial-views

I have a `div` and I want to refresh its content without reloading the entire page.

I tried many times with many methods (ajax call, javascript, etc...), but I don't have did it.

My div displays the entire content of `ModelName.all`
And in this particular div, we can add new entities (thanks to a form) of the Model I use.

I display this div thanks to a Rails Partial View.

Currently, I use this when the user submit the form :

```
$('#ArticlesDiv').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'articles') %>");
```

But it seems my partial view doesn't have an up-to-date model. Because before I add the new entity, I see for example 5 elements, and after I add the new entity, I see again 5 elements. For test purposes, I use a javascript `alert` which displays `ModelName.all.count`

And the alert displays `5` !
But when I look at my database content (before the alert), I can see 6 elements ! And when I refresh my page manually, the `div` displays 6 elements.

Code to explain :

The main view :

```
<div id="ArticlesDiv">
  <%= render(:partial => "articles") %>
</div>
```

_articles (the partial view) :

```
<script>
  alert('<%=Article.all.count%>');
</script>

<% Article.all.each do |article|) %>

<strong><%= article.name %></strong><br />

<% end %>
```

My goal is to have a smooth interface which it doesn't reload the entire page any times you add an other article.

Comment: Where did you written `$('#ArticlesDiv').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'articles') %>");` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the contents of the `div` in a partial and load just the content using a URL say, `/divcontents`. You can refresh the `<div>` using [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#ArticlesDiv').load("/divcontents");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use load function jQuery, you should do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<button type="button" id="button">Test</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // will call refreshPartial every 5 seconds
    setInterval(refreshPartial, 5000)

});

// calls action refreshing the partial
function refreshPartial() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "page_url",
    dataType: 'script',
    format: 'js'
 })
}
</script>
```